# Making CSS Transition Occur More than One Time?

Tags: jquery, css, transform, css-transitions

At the moment I have a simple round logo and when certain ajax functions occur I also make sure that this div rotates 360 degrees.

It does work as I want but it only happens once after a function is triggered and I then have to reload the page to get it to work again.

How do I get the rotation to work anytime the function spin_logo() is triggered into action?

**ROTATION FUNCTION**

```
function spin_logo(){

    var n = 360;
    $('.logo').css({
        transform:'rotate('+n+'deg)',
        '-ms-transform':'rotate('+n+'deg)',
        '-moz-transform':'rotate('+n+'deg)',
        '-o-transform':'rotate('+n+'deg)',
        transition: '1s linear',
        '-ms-transition':'1s linear',
        '-moz-transition':'1s linear',
        '-o-transition':'1s linear'            
    });
    n+=360;

}
```

**ROTATION USE CASE**

spin_logo() occurs just after the success function.

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.publish', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: base_url + "post/publish",
             dataType: "text",  
             data: {
                title: $('.title').html(),
                sub: $('.sub-title').html(),
                txt: $('.editor').html(),
                cat_str: $('#cat-drop').val(),
                str: window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()
             },
             cache:false,
             success: 
              function(data){
                spin_logo();
                $('.response-info').slideToggle(500);
                $('.response-info').html(data).fadeIn(500);   
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.response-info').slideToggle(1000);
                }, 10000);    
            }       

         });                

    return false;
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that 'rotate(360deg)' is the same as 'rotate(720deg)'. Browsers take the degrees mod 360, so, after the first transition, the transform property is not changing at all and nothing happens.

You have to remove the transform after you've done the animation. You can achieve this by using the transitionEnd event. You can see it working here: [http://jsfiddle.net/8rXMw](http://jsfiddle.net/8rXMw/)

```
  var $logo = $('.logo');
  $logo.on('transitionend', function() {
     $logo.removeClass('rotated');
  });

  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $logo.addClass('rotated');
  });
```

What this code does is to add the rotated class to the div, which contains the transform and animation. Once the transition completes, transitionEnd fires and the class is removed. This way, the the div goes back to rotate(0) but without a transition. When you click the button again, the same process repeats.

Be aware that 'transitionEnd' is supported with prefixes in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This could be greatly simplified but using css for animation purpose and jQuery for adding removing classes.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/vm9pv/)**

```
.animate {
    -webkit-animation:rotate 2s infinite linear forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```